# Why cout is not printing string which is evaluated by ternary operator

Tags: c++

I was writing code using ternary operator instead of if/else to save some time in Competitive Programming. But I was stuck in one case and here is the code

```
std::cout<< a%2? "string1" : "string2";
```

OUTPUT on my system: 0 or 1 as per 'a'

Excepted: string1 or string2

I think here ternary operator is returning "const char *" after evaluation, but I'm not getting expected results. So here are my doubts about it.

1. Why `const char * ram = "ram"; std::cout<<ram;` works fine but above code don't, to me both seems to have const char * as input to cout, so what is difference between them?
2. Any workaround to print strings as intended above using ternary operator?

Comment: `std::cout<< (a%2? "string1" : "string2");`

Comment: whoever downvoted it could you suggest me how to improve this question, or because I missed the precedence that's why

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have seen this asked way too many times on this website. This maybe why someone downvoted it.

Comment: Your question was probably downvoted because it's about C++ basics, other than that it looks well-written to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  The phrase "... Competitive Programming ..." may have been a trigger phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator<<` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than ternary conditional operator, so `std::cout<< a%2? "string1" : "string2";` has the same effect as `(std::cout<< a%2) ? "string1" : "string2";`. As the result `a%2` is printed out instead. (`std::cout<< a%2` returns `std::cout`, which could [convert to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), regardless of the result is `true` or `false`, `"string1"` or `"string2"` don't have any effect here.)

You should add parentheses like

```
std::cout<< (a%2? "string1" : "string2");
```

Comment: I got it ; (std::cout<<a%2) ? "string1": "string2" ;  so in this way what is Boolean  value returned by condition part in it. just a follow up question

Comment: @codeitram `std::cout` could [converto to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: @codeitram It's equivalent to `std::cout << a%2;` followed by `std::cout ? "string1" : "string2"`. Using `std::cout` in a condition like this returns true if it did not encouter any problems while printing, now or earlier.

Comment: Got it now @HolyBlackCat